# redmine with redmineCRM or SugarCRM?

Tags: crm, redmine, sugarcrm

My boss asked me to propose a PM web app + a CRM one.

After some time spent for investigation (reading comments, feedbacks, stackoverflow posts etc) I suggested **redmine + [redmineCRM]**[1](http://redminecrm.com/) (site is down right now for some reasons).

Now he asked me *if SugarCRM has any very needed features which redmine(crm) does not have.*

Because I did not work yet with any of these I ask you guys about this: *do you think that redmine with its CRM plugin would be enough? Are you aware of some very important piece which is missing from here and SugarCRM will fit better?*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm a developer of RedmineCRM plugin. I have many plans for new features and modules. If you have any concrete questions I could try to help you. Now I developing helpdesk module for RedmineCRM plugin. Next will be Staff plugin and module for managing products and orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the requirements, but I don't think you can compare the two.

RedmineCRM is mainly for contact+task management, while SugarCRM has a much wider scope (management of account, quote, pipeline, opportunity, task, activity, campaigns, report and much more).

Basically just compare the features list:

- [RedmineCRM features](http://redminecrm.com/)
- [SugarCRM features](http://media.sugarcrm.com/datasheets/EditionsComparison_CE.pdf)